# Power Queries merge/add rows from a file for each column of another query

Tags: merge, append, powerbi, powerquery

I have a query in power BI as follows:

```
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|    
  |       Test          |        Wup          |       Sigma         |    
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
  |         A           |         65465       |       4wr44         |       
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
  |         B           |         56          |       fd54          |          
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
  |         C           |         654564      |        d340         |       
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
```

And another query as follows:

```
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|    
  |       Test          |        Wup          |       Sigma         |    
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
  |       FGET          |        FEEE65       |       4$$wr44       |       
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
  |        GRGT         |        FEF          |       f$§%§d54      |          
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
  |         TRG         |         6FEFE4      |        §%§d340      |       
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
```

I would like to map each columns and get this result:

```
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|    
  |       Test          |        Wup          |       Sigma         |    
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
  |         A           |         65465       |       4wr44         |       
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
  |         B           |         56          |       fd54          |          
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
  |         C           |         654564      |        d340         |       
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|    
  |       Test          |        Wup          |       Sigma         |    
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
  |       FGET          |        FEEE65       |       4$$wr44       |       
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
  |        GRGT         |        FEF          |       f$§%§d54      |          
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
  |         TRG         |         6FEFE4      |        §%§d340      |       
  |---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
```

Here is my code, which is leading to very bad results:

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(#"Snouba", {"Test"}, #"Snouba F", {"Test"}, "Snouba F", JoinKind.FullOuter),
    #"Expanded Snouba F" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Snouba F", {"Test", "Wup", "Sigma"}, {"Snouba F.Test", "Snouba F.Wup", "Snouba F.Sigma"})
in
    #"Expanded Snouba F"
```

Comment: What if you Append instead of Merge?

Comment: Nothing happened. Sadly. I still had single letters. Nothing else. It is sad because it is quite literally a "copy" and "paste" which I would like to implement/ automate, just scrolling at the bottom of one query and pasting the other under the good columns...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be something off with what you're trying because appending should do the trick.

You should be able to either use the GUI or define a new query as

```
let
    Source = Table.Combine({Query1, Query2})
in
    Source
```

which should look like this:

```
  ==================================================================
  |       Test          |        Wup         |       Sigma         |
  ======================+====================+======================
  |         A           |        65465       |       4wr44         |
  |---------------------|--------------------|---------------------|
  |         B           |        56          |       fd54          |
  |---------------------|--------------------|---------------------|
  |         C           |        654564      |       d340          |
  |---------------------|--------------------|---------------------|
  |        FGET         |        FEEE65      |       4$$wr44       |
  |---------------------|--------------------|---------------------|
  |        GRGT         |        FEF         |       f$§%§d54      |
  |---------------------|--------------------|---------------------|
  |        TRG          |        6FEFE4      |       §%§d340       |
  |---------------------|--------------------|---------------------|
```

If you need the column headers repeated, that's possible, but it's not clear if you need that or not.

Comment: Thank you! I do not need the headers repeated. I will keep trying to understand what is wrong on my side with append.